# How to use manual update in avira newest version

Tags: updates, gui, avira

I use Avira ( https://www.avira.com/en/ ) as my antivirus tool, sometimes online update may get an error, so I download virus definition files from websites and use manual update from its avcenter. it works well until some days before a new version was installed, from then on, GUI of old avcenter no longer exist , and only following GUI [image: New GUI] can be started. I cannot find place to do manual update from local disk in this new GUI.

For everyone to see how the old GUI looked like: since I cannot trigger the exact old avcenter any more, so this is the configuration GUI which is somewhat like the old avcenter GUI[image: old mode GUI]

Before the update somedays ago ,I can still double-click "avcenter.exe" to open the old GUI but currently doing this still open the new GUI

Questions:

How can I do an manual update from local downloaded virus definition files in new GUI

AND if possible How to use the exact old GUI avcenter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the new GUI is a bit convoluted, as it includes access to the additional modules (whether or not one uses them).

To manually update in this GUI, click on the underlined "Check for updates" in the panel to the right of "Status".

To reach the familiar GUI for the A-V itself (where all of the traditional settings can be found), click on the small gray gear in the lower-left corner.

These pages of questions & answers may also be useful:
https://support.avira.com/hc/en-us/sections/360000407197-Antivirus-for-Windows .

Comment: @J1B - Your question specifically says you don’t know where the mechanic is hidden.

Comment: Maybe there was some misunderstanding,so I have edited my question again to re-clarify my main problem: how to manually update from local disk virus defenition files in the newest avira software

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will address your need to update Avira manually, offline:  https://www.techspot.com/downloads/1510-avira-antivirus-definition-update.html .

As for the repository of quarantined items, you'll see the link in the left-hand column of this screenshot (fourth from the top):

[image: Avira Free Antivirus]

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the old ("classic") GUI from about five years ago or so, and previous to that, has been completely replaced by what we're dealing with now, unfortunately. (FWIW, Malwarebytes "improved their GUI with version 4xx a few months ago, of which many of us are not particularly enamored.)

Sorry that I was not able to provide the solution you are seeking.

Perhaps you might try communicating with Avira directly, by contacting their customer service address.

Good luck! (And if you *do* discover a useful answer, please be sure to post it.)

All the best.

Comment: What does Malwarebytes have to do with the author’s question?  Why have you submitted three answers to the same question?